# How to rewrite this code using rxjs observables instead async/await?

Tags: rxjs, nestjs

I need that createUser function returns `Observable<UserEntity>` but in this function I also have to make 2 queries to DB and check if this user exists. The code below uses async/await and looks pretty good and clean. But the problem is that I use rxjs everywhere in this project and would like to write it somehow using rxjs. Can it be as clean as now but with Observables?

```
async create(user: CreateUserDTO): Promise<UserEntity> {
    const userByEmail = await this.getUserByEmail(); 

    const userByLogin = await this.getUserByLogin(); 
    if (userByLogin || userByEmail)
        // retrun error here

    return await this.createUser(user);
}
```

Comment: You should probably rewrite getUserByEmail, getUserByLogin and createUser functions to Observables too, but it's hard to help with that unless we have the code for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `RxJs 6.5`

**`forkJoin`** will emit result when both async functions `getUserByEmail` & `getUserByLogin` complete their execution

If `getUserByEmail` & `getUserByLogin` returns Promise,for that using **`from`** to convert a **promise** into an **observable**

**`mergeMap`** to subscribe the inner observable.In our case `createUser` returns observable

```ts
create(user: CreateUserDTO): Observable < UserEntity > {

    //If getUserByEmail & getUserByLogin returs Promise

    const getUserByEmail$ = from(this.getUserByEmail());
    const getUserByLogin$ = from(this.getUserByLogin());

    //If Both returns Observable
    //const getUserByEmail$ = this.getUserByEmail();
    //const getUserByLogin$ = this.getUserByLogin();


    return forkJoin({
        userByEmail: this.getUserByEmail(),
        userByLogin: this.getUserByLogin(),
    }).pipe(
        tap((res) => {
            if (res.userByEmail || res.userByLogin) {
                throw 'User exists!';
            }
        }),
        mergeMap(() => {
            return from(this.createUser(user));
            //If createUser returns Observable,then
            //return this.createUser(user);
        })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `this.getUserByEmail()`, `this.getUserByLogin()` and `this.createUser(user)` return `Promise`s, the code could look like this

```
create(user: CreateUserDTO): Observable<UserEntity> {
    // with the rxjs from function we turn a Promise into an Observable
    const userByEmail$ = from(this.getUserByEmail()); 
    const userByLogin$ = from(this.getUserByLogin()); 

    // with forkjoin we create an Observable which notifies when all the 
    // Observables which have been passed in as parameters notify
    return forkJoin([userByEmail$, userByLogin$]).pipe(
       // with concatMap you wait for the upstream Observable (i.e. the 
       // Observable created by forkJoin) to notify and complete, and then
       // you return the next Observable in the chain, which is, in this case,
       // the Observable which (when subscribed) creates the user
       concatMap(([userByLogin, userByEmail]) => 
          if (userByLogin || userByEmail) {
              // throw error here
          }
          return from(this.createUser(user))
       })
    )
}
```

Otherwise, if `this.getUserByEmail()`, `this.getUserByLogin()` and `this.createUser(user)` return `Observable`s you do not need to use the `from` rxjs function and the code would be slightly simpler, like this

```
create(user: CreateUserDTO): Observable<UserEntity> {
    return forkJoin([this.getUserByEmail(), this.getUserByLogin()]).pipe(
       concatMap(([userByLogin, userByEmail]) => 
          if (userByLogin || userByEmail) {
              // throw error here
          }
          return from(this.createUser(user))
       })
    )
}
```

Comment: Why you used concatMap operator in this case?

Comment: `concatMap` is the go-to operator any time you have standard sequential async calls to be made. When I say "standard" I mean that you do not have the requirement to kill the request on fly if a new notification comes from upstream (e.g. if you run a query when you click a button and you want to kill that query, if still on fly, if the button is clicked again - in this case the operator to use is `switchMap`). What may dangerous is `mergeMap` which keeps all the request and can end up returning not the freshest result. Anyways, it depends on the requirements.

Comment: You may find interesting [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a) which talks about typical patterns of use of rxjs operators with http.